# What do decomposers eat if they break down complex substances and make it available for producers?

Tags: food, decomposition, food-web

I have a doubt for which I haven't found the exact answer.

Decomposers break down complex substances into simpler substances and make it available for producers. *But what does decomposers get (or eat) in this process.*

Answer with an **example** would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Homework questions are off topic unless you show an attempt to answer it on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is stored energy in complex substances: that's what the decomposers use.  For instance, if you've ever made bread, you'll have seen yeast decompose sugars & starches (complex substances) into less-complex CO2 and ethanol, using the energy released to reproduce.